# AWK: how to divide 2nd to 4th row with 1st row value for every 5 rows

Tags: awk

I have thousand rows of input.txt , each row contains 1 number after "grep".

I want to have 2nd to 4th row numbers from every 5 rows divided by 1st row from every 5 rows, until end of the file.

The way I am using is

```
paste - - - - - - <input.txt >lines.txt
```

which converts 5 rows into one row, and then

```
awk '{print $2/$1,$3/$1,$4/$1,$5/$1}' lines.txt
```

This is kinda of complex. Is there any better ways to do that ?

Thanks.

updated
e.g. INPUT (one number at one row)
1
2
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
.....

Desired OUTPUT
2
3
4
5
1.1667
1.3333
1.5
1.6667
.....

Before grep, there are actually more useless columns/rows, I just throw them away.
I am new to Unix command. I learned a lot from this website. Thanks for all the kind people who wants to share their experiences with us. Really appreciate!

Comment: Why not just do the whole thing with a single awk script ?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show a sample of your input along with the desired output? At the moment it's unclear exactly what you want.

Comment: ... and show the input BEFORE the grep command you are currently running as that grep is not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the whole thing using awk:

```
awk '{if(NR%5==1)a=$1;else $1/=a}1' input.txt
```

The `if` branch is taken on lines 1,6,11,etc. It saves the value of the first field in the variable `a`.

The `else` branch is taken on all other lines and divides the values of the field by `a`.

The `1` at the end is a common shorthand for `{print}`, meaning that every line in the input file is printed.

Testing it out:

```
$ seq 10 | awk '{if(NR%5==1)a=$1;else $1/=a}1'
1
2
3
4
5
6
1.16667
1.33333
1.5
1.66667
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use

```
awk '{ n = $1; for(i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) { v = 0; getline v; $i = v / n } } 1' filename
```

That is:

```
{
  n = $1                       # remember divisor

  for(i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {    # four times:

    v = 0                      # Reset base value (to achieve the same output
                               # as the original approach in case the number
                               # of input lines is not cleanly divisible by 5)

    getline v                  # fetch a new line into variable v (if there
                               # are no more lines, v is unchanged)

    $i = v / n                 # set the ith field in the output to that line
                               # divided by the divisor
  }
}
1                              # then print
```

Example output:

```
$ seq 1 12 | awk '{ n = $1; for(i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) { v = 0; getline v; $i = v / n } } 1'
2 3 4 5
1.16667 1.33333 1.5 1.66667
1.09091 0 0 0
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `v=0`

Comment: @JID Not if the number of lines is cleanly divisible by 5. Otherwise not resetting it would change the output compared to the original script. (In the `seq 1 12` example, the last line would become `1.09091 1.09091 1.09091 1.09091`).

Answer (score 0):

This does what you seem to want. Using `seq` as the input

```
$ seq 10 | awk '
    NR % 5 == 1 {n=$1; next} 
                {printf "%f ", $1/n} 
    NR % 5 == 0 {print ""}
    END         {print ""}
'
2.000000 3.000000 4.000000 5.000000 
1.166667 1.333333 1.500000 1.666667
```

Comment: This will need an end block to print if number of lines is not a multiple of 5.